# R-Studio ggplot: my face_wrap plots are cut off, how can I make the plots wider?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to create 6 line graphs using ggplot and face_wrap. However the plots are always cramped and cut off so that you can't read the x-axes labels and it seems that the graphs are cut off too. How can I make them wider and adjust the text of the x-axis so that I can see everything?

[image: image of my plots]

This is the code I have so far:

```
MPO8_marchapril_2020 <- read.csv("~/TU Berlin/3. Semester/MuB/Laermdaten Schoenefeld/MPO8_marchapril_2020.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=TRUE, dec=",")
str(MPO8_marchapril_2020)
library(tidyr)
datagather2=gather(data = MPO8_marchapril_2020, key = "type of measurements", value = "sound pressure levels", -Datum, -Messstelle)
View(datagather2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(datagather2, aes(x=Datum,y=`sound pressure levels`, color=`type of measurements`, group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title="blabla - 2020", x="", y="")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30, face="plain"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=15, angle=90), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=25),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=25))+
  facet_wrap(~`type of measurements`)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!!

Comment: If you're doing this interactively, then just make the plot window/pane larger. If you're doing it programmatically (e.g., `pdf(...)` as @akaDrHouse suggested), then just make the canvas larger with width/height. Otherwise, just insert `\n` and/or use `paste(strwrap(...), collapse="\n")` to force multi-line facet labels.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to print to pdf and specify width/height options.  You can then play with different dimensions to match your plots.

```
ggplot(datagather2, aes(x=Datum,y=`sound pressure levels`, color=`type of measurements`, group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title="blabla - 2020", x="", y="")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30, face="plain"), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=15, angle=90), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.x=element_text(size=25),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=25))+
  facet_wrap(~`type of measurements`) -> plotforpdf

pdf(file = "path.myplotname.pdf", height = 7, width = 12) #default is inches
print(plotforpdf)
dev.off() # close the pdf printer device
```